# Putting the item of a List into Html.RenderPartial("item", i) looses index binding context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My IEnumberable is a null parameter in my action. The binding does not work anymore since I did this:

**BEFORE** my refactoring

The **ListItem**.cshtml was inside the **List**.html

```
<table id="TeststepsDataTable">
           <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {

                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(item => item[i].UnitId)
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(item => item[i].Name)
                        </td>                    
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**AFTER** my refactoring

**List**.cshtml

```
<table id="TeststepsDataTable">
           <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("ListItem", Model[i]);
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**ListItem**.cshtml

```
@model ITMS.Web.Models.Teststep.TeststepViewModel

<tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.UnitId)
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Name)
    </td>        
</tr>
```

When my save button in the List.cshtml is clicked this action is triggered:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<TeststepViewModel> teststepViewModels)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

The teststepViewModels are null because I lost index property stuff like [0].UnitId so the modelbinder can NOT correctly bind the properties.

How can I fix that?

I really want to use the ListItem.cshtml because I want to reuse this code for an Insert/Add operation an empty row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach instead of for

```
    <table id="TeststepsDataTable">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("ListItem", item);

        }        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and also you have to bind this way

```
<tr>
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.UnitId)
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Name)
</td>
```

and, Lock at the expression ***item=> item.UnitId*** instead of ***item=> Model.UnitId***

***Edit***

i added an index property to model

```
    public class UnitsViewModel
{
    public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }

    public class Unit
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]

        public int UnitId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string ErrorText { get; set; }

        public int Index { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in main view i fill index property :

```
    <table id="TeststepsDataTable">
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Units.Count; i++)
        {
            Model.Units[i].Index = i;
            Html.RenderPartial("ListItem", Model.Units[i]);
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in listItem :

```
@model StackOverflowSample.Models.UnitsViewModel.Unit
```

```
@Html.Hidden("Units["+ Model.Index +"].UnitId",Model.UnitId)
<td>
    @Html.TextBox("Units["+ Model.Index +"].Name",Model.Name)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBox("Units["+ Model.Index +"].ErrorText",Model.ErrorText)
</td>
```

i change Editor to TextBox ,HiddenFor to Hidden.it's Work ;)

Comment: No I can not use a foreach => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866450/model-binding-generic-list-is-null-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: can i see your model ?
i think you use IEnumerable in your view instead of List.when you use IEnumerable you can't use index and you have getenumerate it, and you can use while instead of for

Comment: also i think it wont post all your data to action with this structure and always Save(IEnumerable<TeststepViewModel> teststepViewModels) will be null, but in your header you see all data passed to action

Comment: Please have a look at the Update part of my post

Comment: I am using a List<MyViewModel> in my List.cshtml because with the IEnumerable the indexing did not work.

Comment: I did what you say but as I said before the binding does NOT work because its only possible to bind a generic List when you use a for loop not foreach.

Comment: also if you want MultilineText you can use TextArea

Comment: Its that messy that I do not want to try it out :P But thank you for the time you invested.