# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while rendering textbox in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

WHen Control comes to following helper,object ref error occurs , I don't know why?

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SundayDriveTime, new {@class = "smallTxtEntry0 daysDriveTime sundayDriveTime", @id = "PredefinedDriveTimeDetailsList_" + i + "_SundayDriveTime", oldValue = Model[i].SundayDriveTime, @onchange = "driveTimeDayValuesOnchnge(this)" })</td>
```

Model count is not zero and also SundayDriveTime alos has value 
My model is :`@model List<PredefinedDriveTimeDetails>`

It does not show error while rendering other text boxes.

what is the problem??

Comment: Show the loop where you use this code. I guess it has to do with the m in `m[i]`, but my crystal ball doesn't help me further.

Comment: @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {<td style="vertical-align: middle;">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SaturdayDriveTime)</td>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SundayDriveTime)</td>}

Comment: Razor errors can sometimes be a little misleading; it's possible that the actual error is in a very different location than that line of code. Try commenting out that/those `TextBoxFor`s and see if the issue continues to occur?

Answer (score 0):

Got your for loop code from comment. what you are doing wrong is referencing `m => m[i]` which should be `m => Model[i]`

Try using following code

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].SaturdayDriveTime)</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].SundayDriveTime)</td>
}
```

References

[ASP.NET MVC 4 - for loop posts model collection properties but foreach does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not)

[MVC with TextBoxFor having same id within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955178/mvc-with-textboxfor-having-same-id-within-loop)

[MVC 3 - Model Binding a list in a table with each record being a column instead of row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885679/mvc-3-model-binding-a-list-in-a-table-with-each-record-being-a-column-instead)

Comment: @eouw0o83hf: Please see my added references.

Comment: Wow, color me surprised. Deleting my previous remark because it's apparently just wrong and misleading.